# How to enable review form tab only after click on Add your review link or on review count in product details page magento 2?

Tags: magento2

How to enable review form tab only after click on Add your review link or on review count in product details page magento 2 custom theme?

Answer (score 0):

In magento2 you can remove any block by their name.
For exp:

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
```

To do this we need to create a custom theme, don't touch the default Magento file for best practice. For create a theme follow this link : How to create a Child Theme in Magento 2, If you have already a custom theme skip this one.

Now open `app/design/frontend/theme_package/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` and under  node put the following code:

```
<referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true"/>
```

Clear your magento cache refresh the page.
In the same way you can remove other unnecessary block from your site.

Comment: this code is useful to remove review and review form but i want to enable review tab when we click on custom Add your review link or review count link